# Why can you use relative clauses with implicit complementisers or relative pronouns?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns, relative-pronouns, construction, reduced-relative-clauses

Why are these correct?

> 1. The work I am doing is easy.
> 2. The house he lives at.
> 3. The book I am writing is about different realms.
> 4. The man I was helping thanked me.
> 5. The ant I was blocking the road of.
> 6. The school I go to.

Shouldn't "I am doing", "lives at", "writing", "was helping", "blocking", and "go" be at the front? Could you please explain the grammar here? Thank you.

Comment: You should read about the basics of **reduced relative clauses**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause. If this is too advanced, check your grammar book.

Comment: 2 and 6 are sentence fragments and therefore, it's pointless to comment on their correctness or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, the relative pronoun "that" has been omitted.

> The work **that** I am doing is easy.
>
> The house **that** he lives at
>
> The book **that** I am writing is about different realms.
>
> The man **that/who** I was helping thanked me.
>
> The ant **that** I was blocking the road of
>
> The school **that** I go to

Such clauses are, as @legatrix comments, called [reduced relative clauses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause), wherein the [complementiser](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer) or [relative pronoun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun) is ***implicit***.